# Why is GraalVM + native-image slower than GraalVM alone on a while loop?

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Just for fun, I'm trying to compare gcc (9.4.0), OpenJDK (11.0.12), GraalVM (22.3.r19) and GraalVM + native-image (22.3.r19) performances on a "while loop n++" use case (see programs below).

Bottom line on Linux is (see results below): native-image is slower than all other options.

So I'm wondering: am I missing something (magic command-line option)? Or is it just life that native-image is slower on this particular program (and that's fine)?

Count.java

```
public class Count {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 0;
    int inc = Math.random() >= 0 ? 1 : 0; // to prevent the optimizer from removing the loop
    while (n < 1000000000) {
      n += inc;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
  }
}
```

count.c

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n = 0;
  srand(time(NULL));
  int inc = rand() >= 0 ? 1 : 0; // to prevent the optimizer from removing the loop
  while (n < 1000000000) {
    n += inc;
  }
}
```

gcc:

```
me@laptop:~/dev/java-count-graalvm$ gcc -O2 -s -DNDEBUG count.c -o count
me@laptop:~/dev/java-count-graalvm$ time ./count

real    0m0,261s
user    0m0,261s
sys 0m0,000s
```

OpenJDK 11:

```
me@laptop:~/dev/java-count-graalvm$ time java -classpath target/classes Count
1000000000

real    0m0,632s
user    0m0,612s
sys 0m0,030s
```

GraalVM:

```
me@laptop:~/dev/java-count-graalvm$ time java -classpath target/classes Count
1000000000

real    0m0,326s
user    0m0,362s
sys 0m0,013s
```

GraalVM native-image:

```
me@laptop:~/dev/java-count-graalvm$ native-image -cp target/classes Count
me@laptop:~/dev/java-count-graalvm$ time ./count 
1000000000

real    0m1,283s
user    0m1,271s
sys 0m0,013s
```

For the sake of sanity, I commented-out the while loop and native image is returning in 3 milliseconds:

```
bruno@hearne:~/dev/java-count-graalvm$ time ./count 
0

real    0m0,003s
user    0m0,000s
sys 0m0,003s
```

So I would say that the penalty is coming from the while loop and nothing else.